# Future-safe version numbers in pip freeze output

Tags: python, deployment, pip

If i type `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, the resulting file looks similar to this:

```
argparse==1.2.1  
h5py==2.2.0  
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Some libraries are under ongoing development. This happened to me regarding h5py, which is now (as of this writing) available in version `2.2.1`. Thus, using `pip install -r requirements.txt` throws an error, saying version `2.2.0` of h5py was not found:

```
No distributions matching the version for h5py==2.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

Is it considered good practice to maintain the requirements via `pip freeze` at all? Obviously, I can not rely on specific version numbers being still available in the future. I would like to deploy my applications in the future, even if they are several years old, without compatibility problems regarding version numbers. Is there a way to make the output of `pip freeze` future-safe?

I thought about manipulating the output file of `pip freeze` by using the *greater than* symbol `>=` instead of the *equals* symbol `==`, so the output would look like the following:

```
argparse>=1.2.1  
h5py>=2.2.0  
wsgiref>=0.1.2
```

But I can imagine that this will break my applications if any of the libraries breaks backward-compatibility in a future version.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the first question, yes, it is pretty common to use pip freeze to manage requirements. If your project is packaged you can also set dependencies directly in the setup.py file.

You can set the requirements to greater than or equal to version x, but as you speculate, this can turn around and bite you if a dependency makes changes to their api that break your required functionality. You can also ensure that an installed dependency is less than a certain version. i.e. If you're on version 1.0 of a package and would like minor updates but a major release scares you (whether its released yet or not) you can require example>=1.0.0,<2.0.0

[More info on requirements files](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files)

In the end, `pip freeze` is just a tool to show you what you currently have installed, it doesn't know, or care, if it works for you. What you use to replicate environments based on this data also doesn't really matter; version conflicts, updates breaking backwards compatibility, bugs and other such issues in dependencies will (at least once) cause you grief. Keeping tabs on the state of your project's major dependencies and doing automated testing with new versions will save you a lot of time and headache (or at least headache).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. Could you add some information on how to actually manage dependencies in a future-safe way? I heard about hosting your own repository. So pip would not search in the official index but instead rely on your own server. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: you certainly can manage your own repo, though most only do this for internally created packages. Managing external packages in your own repo is a pain (but doable).

Comment: To manage your external third-party dependencies in your own repository use: 

"--find-links https://myrepo.com"

at the top of your requirements.txt. The cost is that you have to update your cheeseshop (repo) whenever you want to (stably) update a dependency in your project. If you are producing anything commercial, I highly recommend taking control of your dependencies.